# HTML Table - split row to 2 cells in the middle of the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with three columns. I want one of the rows to have only two cells, but the line separator of the cells will be in the middle of the table.

How do I do it?

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Data 1   | Data 2   | Data 3   |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Data 1   | Data 2   | Data 3   |
|----------+----------+----------+
|      aaa      |       bbb      |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Data 1   | Data 2   | Data 3   |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Data 1   | Data 2   | Data 3   |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Data 1   | Data 2   | Data 3   |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: `colspan=2` for all the cells in all other rows, and `colspan=3` for those in that special row ...?

Comment: Indeed, a SIX column table? But honestly, what is the purpose of these wider cells. It looks more like it should be a sub-table.

Comment: @CBroe Can you show a code example + result? I can't make it work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z8L4d1j7/

Answer (score -1):

You could go this way:

```
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
```

Or my preferred way as I love CSS grid is to use CSS Grid:

```css
.grid-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* Creates three columns of equal width */
  grid-gap: 1px; /* This creates the lines between the cells */
  background-color: black; /* The lines' color */
}

.cell {
  background-color: white; /* Background color of cells */
  padding: 10px; /* Padding inside the cells */
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold; /* Make header cells bold */
}

.double {
  grid-column: span 2; /* Make the 'aaa' cell span two columns */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-table">
  <div class="cell header">Data 1</div>
  <div class="cell header">Data 2</div>
  <div class="cell header">Data 3</div>

  <div class="cell">Data 1</div>
  <div class="cell">Data 2</div>
  <div class="cell">Data 3</div>

  <div class="cell double">aaa</div>
  <div class="cell">bbb</div>

  <div class="cell">Data 1</div>
  <div class="cell">Data 2</div>
  <div class="cell">Data 3</div>

  <div class="cell">Data 1</div>
  <div class="cell">Data 2</div>
  <div class="cell">Data 3</div>

  <!-- More cells as needed -->
</div>
```